# What does "The indexes PRIMARY and id seem to be equal and one of them could possibly be removed." mean?

Tags: mysql, indexing

[image: Indexes]
What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it telling you the records are basically duplicates?

Comment: No, it is saying the indexes are identical and having both of them serves no purpose. It has nothing to do with records (unless you are referring to records within the index table, of course). @thkala has the right answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two separate indexes on the same field of your table (`id`). One of them is implied by having set `id` as a `PRIMARY KEY`, the other you probably created explicitly. Only one of them is needed - having both of them may result in performance drop due to the additional index updates.

Just [drop](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-index.html) one of them to resolve this issue.

Having a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on a column (or field, if you wish) of a table essentially means that for each row inserted, the value of that column should be unique and therefore it should not already exist in the table. The naive approach would be to read all existing rows before inserting, but that would make the DB *very* slow once a number of rows has been inserted.

In order to deal with this, most (all?) decent database engines will *implicitly* create indexes for such fields, so that they can quickly detect if a value already exists in the table, without having to scan all its rows.

As a result, manually creating indexes on fields declared `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` not only is redudant, but it may also cause performance loss due to the duplication of the work needed to maintain the indexes.

Comment: So how do I fix it? I'm still a bit new with mySQL.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton Try clicking the 'X' icon next to the index you wish to delete.

Comment: @djacobson, I thought about that. But if I delete my manually created field, how does PRIMARY KEY keep track of records?

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: just having a PRIMARY KEY implicitly creates an index on many SQL engines - you do not have to create it on you own.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton I think you're confusing separate concepts: an Index and a Primary Key [are not the same thing](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/difference-between-an-index-and-a-primary-key/). However, MySQL creates an index by default when you specify a primary key, because it generally makes sense to index a field that will often be referenced.

Comment: *"But if I delete my manually created field, how does PRIMARY KEY keep track of records?"* To answer this another way: You are not deleting the *field*, you are deleting one of the *indexes* on that field.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what caused it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that it's saying both of these indices have the exact same properties and just have different Keynames, having two indices will create extra storage space as well as run-time to inserts (there is no reason to do this that I can think of) more detail on the topic can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

the PRIMARY one is created by phpMyAdmin I believe and it appears the index one was created manually, but is a duplication of work.