# MySQL CREATE produces redundant index

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

When creating a new database table with the following code phpMyAdmin reports a redundant index like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506417/what-does-the-indexes-primary-and-id-seem-to-be-equal-and-one-of-them-could-pos). Is there a way to avoid this behavior and have only one index produced on table creation? I could remove the second index with `ALTER TABLE mytest DROP INDEX id;` but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

```
<?php
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytest` (
    `id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    `mytext` TEXT
  ) CHARSET=utf8";
  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

  $sql = "SHOW INDEX FROM `mytest`";
  if ($res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    while ($ds = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($ds);
      echo "</pre>";
    }
  } else echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.

Hence, your declaration is:

```
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY
```

So, you are getting an index for `UNIQUE` and an index for `PRIMARY KEY`.

The simple solution is to not use "abbreviations" and be clear about what you want:

```
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```